# Child object unable to delete parent in before_destroy callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I building a calender Rails app.
It has Events, which can have one or more Recurring Events.
E.g "Running every Monday, 100 times."

If a user deletes all of the recurring events, then I want the main Event also to be deleted.

```
1 class RecurringEvent < ApplicationRecord
27   belongs_to :event
35   after_destroy :delete_main_event_if_last_current

118   def delete_main_event_if_last_current
119     puts "#{event.recurring_events.size} left"
120     event.destroy if event.recurring_events.empty?
121   end
```

**My test**

```
   87     it "Delete the main event when the last recurring is deleted", focus: true do
   88       event_id = @event.id
   89       @event.recurring_events.each { |re| re.destroy! }
   90       expect(Event.where(id: event_id).count).to eq 0
   91     end
```

That yields this output, but the main Event is not delete.

```
RecurringEvent
  Recurring events
5 left
5 left
5 left
5 left
5 left
```

Any idea why I the recurring events will not be deleted?

With `byebug`:

```
[117, 126] in /app/app/models/recurring_event.rb
   117:
   118:   def delete_main_event_if_last_current
   119:     puts "#{event.recurring_events.size} left"
   120:     event.destroy if event.recurring_events.empty?
   121:     byebug
=> 122:   end
   123:

(byebug) event.recurring_events.size
5
(byebug) event.recurring_events.first.destroy
nil
(byebug) event.recurring_events.size
5
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks that `event.recurring_events` is cached in application and you're checking a stale version of this collection. You should query DB instead. I can see two options.

You can reload association in every callback

```
event.destroy if event.recurring_events.reload.empty?
```

Or check the count of elements remaining in the collection:

```
event.destroy if event.recurring_events.count == 0 #it should query the DB
```

Note that if you run this check **before** destroy it still won't work in this form. You should either check if the event being deleted is the last one or perform deletion of the parent **after** deleting the child.

More about caching in [Rails Guides](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#controlling-caching)

Comment: Yeah, the reload did the trick. Thanks! I tested with `before_destroy` to see if that worked, as `after_destroy` didn't. Reverted to `after_destroy` now. Green tests. :-)